# add the name of line into legend in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I made a graph with actual data and drew a dashed line. I cannot include the dashed line into the legend. It shows a straight line. Any ideas why? Here is the code I used

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.95)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={left},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$t$} [{\myfont min}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=3,
    xtick={0,1,...,3},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$F$} [{\myfont N}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=150,
    ytick={0,50,...,150},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]
    %\addplot [black,thick] file {force1.txt};

    %\addplot [black,thick] file {force2.txt};

    \addplot [black,thick] file {force3.txt};
    \addlegendentry{\large{\myfont experimental}}

    \draw [black,dashed,thick] (0,84) -- (3,84);
    \addlegendentry{\large{\myfont model prediction}}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\addplot[color=black,dashed,thick] coordinates {(0,84)  (3,84)};` should do.

Comment: I simplified the code by removing other 2 curves but I can see that it is misleading. 

    %\addplot [black,thick] file {force1.txt};

    %\addplot [black,thick] file {force2.txt};

    \addplot [black,thick] file {force3.txt};
    \addlegendentry{\large{\myfont experimental}}

    \draw [black,dashed,thick] (0,84) -- (3,84);
    \addlegendentry{\large{\myfont model prediction}}

Comment: The issue is that you cannot just add a legend for a line you draw with `\draw`, but if you draw the line with `\addplot`, you can.

Comment: Okay, I get the difference between \addplot and \draw. However, when I add two more curves with the same legend "experimental", the outcome becomes a plain line for "model prediction".

Comment: Not if you do things in the correct order. Just move the plots for which you do not want a legend after `\addlegendentry{\large{\myfont model prediction}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess in this case the simplest fix is (I do not have your data file, so I had to make sth up)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.95)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={left},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$t$} [{\myfont min}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=3,
    xtick={0,1,...,3},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$F$} [{\myfont N}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=150,
    ytick={0,50,...,150},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]
    %\addplot [black,thick] file {force1.txt};

    %\addplot [black,thick] file {force2.txt};

    \addplot [black,thick,smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (0.1,90) (0.6,70) (3,73)};
    \addlegendentry{\large{\myfont experimental}}

    \addplot[color=black,dashed,thick] coordinates {(0,84) (3,84)};
    \addlegendentry{\large{\myfont model prediction}}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also play with `\addlegendimage` and so on, but in this case that would be more effort.